# Compute $\lim_{p\to 1+}\left\|f\right\|_{p}$ where $f\in L^{1}[0,1] \cap L^{2} [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $f\in L^{1}[0,1] \cap L^{2} [0,1]$. Compute $\lim_{p\to 1+}\left\|f\right\|_{p}$.

I think the result would be $\left\|f\right\|_{1}$,but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dominated convergence theorem with $\max(1,|f(x)|^2)$ as the dominating function.

Comment: This might still be too hard for the OP. Maybe you could add some more hint?